# MySQL INSERT in a CASE as a subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a following situation I would like to get done using only MySQL.

```
CASE 'some_boolean'
(
  WHEN true THEN
     //COMPLEX INSERT HERE
  WHEN FALSE THEN
     //DIFFERENT COMPLEX INSERT HERE
)
END
```

I know I could do this with PHP but the code would get cluttered so I'd prefer to use MySQL but I don't have the faintest idea how the syntax should be or if it's even possible to do this.

Thanks :)

Edit:
By complex I mean that it gets it's insert data from a SELECT.

Edit2:
Here's the SQL I'm trying to get working in detail. It has some PHP input marked with ":".

```
CASE (SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0,true,false) AS structure FROM structures WHERE product_number = "123")
    WHEN true THEN
        INSERT INTO product_balance (product_number,balance)
        (
            SELECT :product_number, product_count * :order_count FROM structures WHERE product_number = :product_number
        )
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE balance = balance + (product_count * :order_count)
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO product_balance (product_number,balance)
        VALUES(:product_number,:order_count)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE balance = balance + (product_count * :order_count)
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Syntax:*

```
IF condition1 THEN
   {...statements to execute when condition1 is TRUE...}

[ ELSEIF condition2 THEN
   {...statements to execute when condition2 is TRUE...} ]

[ ELSE
   {...statements to execute when both condition1 and condition2 are FALSE...} ]

END IF;
```

*Example:*

```
DELIMITER //  
CREATE FUNCTION IncomeLevel ( monthly_value INT )
RETURNS varchar(20)\

BEGIN
   DECLARE income_level varchar(20);

   IF monthly_value <= 4000 THEN
      SET income_level = 'Low Income';
   ELSEIF monthly_value > 4000 AND monthly_value <= 7000 THEN
      SET income_level = 'Avg Income';
   ELSE
      SET income_level = 'High Income';
   END IF;

   RETURN income_level;
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

source: http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/loops/if_then.php

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't what I'm after :/

Comment: Or can I use SELECT in the IF THEN SET?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CASE 'some_boolean'
  WHEN true THEN
     //COMPLEX INSERT HERE
  ELSE
     //DIFFERENT COMPLEX INSERT HERE
END
```

Check [**Manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

Comment: Can you post how can you write in `CASE`?